# Looping in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Thank you for coming by my question.

I create a macro for splitting the timestamp in Google Sheets like this.

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function SplittingTimestamp() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=SPLIT(A2," ")');
  spreadsheet.getRange('B3').activate();
};
```

Basically, the macro is to split the timestamp column whenever a new form submit is sent.
And the Timestamp is the A column and A will be split into B (Date) and C(Time).
I want to loop this macro for each new submission.

[image: Illustration]

I understand that this line of code `spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=SPLIT(A2," ")');` should be A3, A4, A5 and so on whenever a new submission is received. But I don't know how to loop this function. I came across some other problems but I cannot figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to make it as a single formula that will SPLIT all the date and time in column A, you can try this formula below:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>""), " "))
```

[image]

Let me know if this solves your problem.